# Lookup for large list on xPage

Tags: xpages

I have a list of approx 10K entries (and growing) I need to be able to reference in an xPages app.  I have had lookup limitations using @DbLookup, so have looked at other options.  Unfortunately I continue to run into these limitations.

I am currently loading the lookup list into a session scope variable on page load (which has performance impacts), and the reference the scoped variable for the combo box.

I am using the following simple process to load the list for the combo box.  This, however, is also running into limitations.

```
var lookupView:NotesView = database.getView("LookupView");
sessionScope.lookupList = lookupView.getColumnValues(0) + "|" + lookupView.getColumnValues(4);
```

I would like a method to perform a lookup that can handle the larger list (main priority) with performance being number 2.  The page is used by a limited number of users with the function being most important.

Comment: What Per said should solve the issue with retrieving the large amount of data. Caching it in a scope should (for the server side) solve most of the performance issues. Next issue might be the performance on the client: a <select> (combobox) element with that amount of data is a bad idea. You might want to look at Select2: it can take the user input, perform a query on the server and show the results in the client. Maybe you can get some more inspiration from this article series I wrote: https://linqed.eu/2018/11/02/query-domino-data-with-domino-jna-part-3-rest-api-and-infinite-scroll/

Comment: Another option is Extension Library Value Picker with search option. That can point to a view for the dataProvider, with the dominoViewValuePicker dataProvider

Comment: Thanks Paul.  I assumed the value picker would have the same issue with amount of data as I am using the view at the moment?  I will look into it.

Comment: Probably not, though it's some years since I looked at the code. If it's working like a dominoView datasource, it may only load a limited set from the ViewNavigator and lazy load as required. Sending HTML for 10,000 entries alone will take a long time, irrespective of the time to iterate the collection and build the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this code snippet ["Pure Java version of DbLookup & DbColumn, with cache, sort and unique"](https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=pure-java-version-of-dblookup-dbcolumn-with-cache-sort-and-unique) and either use it directly or use it as inspiration.

You should consider storing the list in application scope since it seems that the list is the same for all users. This means that you need to change the code in the code snippet to use applicationScope instead of sessionScope.

Comment: Thank you - yes, it is the same for all users as it is a static lookup list.  It makes sense to move it to the application scope.  I will check the link.  Appreciate the link.

Comment: Just a reminder - if the content of the source view changes overtime, application scope will not be updated. You need to restart http task to refresh its value (there are few other ways to flush scope variables, though).

Answer (score 1):

I doubt your users want or need to pick some value from combo with 10k+ lines.

Rethink your approach, you can use autocomplete feature with dynamic filter/search in live view (no scoped variable needed), as pointed by Mark. Another approach is to divide that values into some groups and split that combo to two or three with cascading choose/lookup function. First one picks one group, second one looks up only options from first group. That way you probably won't hit that @DbLookup limitations.